# nodejs console multiline command?

Tags: node.js

How do I execute commands that span multiple lines in nodejs console. For example,

```
> var o = { x : 1, y : 2, z : 3}
undefined
> delete x.y
> for(var q in o) print q
...
...
```

how do I tell js to execute that for statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, but will print out x, y, and z for the above code.

```
> for (var q in o) console.log(q)
```

If you want the numbers, you can do

```
> for (var q in o) console.log(o[q])
```

And finally, you could display `key: value`:

```
> for (var q in o) {
... console.log(q + ': ' + o[q]);
... }
```

Comment: thanks. I was using print and was surprised to find out that node didn't give me any error when print was undefined.